# SFML Sprite is changing the position of the texture when setting an origin

Tags: c++, sprite, sfml

I'm recently trying to build a program by myself, and for this reason I need to make a Sprite bigger when the MouseCursor is over it. Is solved it by checking for Mouse movement and then checking if ths mouse is over the Sprite. I increase the size of the sprite by using the `setScale();` function. The problem then was, that the Sprite has been enlarged, but the center of the Sprite has been moved. I tried to set the Origin to the center of the Sprite, but now, the texture is at an other place than the Sprite.

The Texture is 500x500px large, so I set the origin to 250, 250. The Texture of the sprite moved to the right spot, since the origin is at an other place. The Position is "50, 250", so the texture is slightly off the screen. When I set a new position, the texture moves, but the sprite also. So texture and sprite don't match anymore.

Does anyone know how to fix the problem?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: The origin also affects the position, use `Sprite::setPosition` to correctly place the Sprite

Comment: @DarkPhantom I know that I have to set thr position new. I also have made this, and the Texture AND the Sprite have been set to the new position. But as I said: Sprite and Texture are offset.

Edit: The Upper left corner of the Sprite, is now in the middle (the new origin) of the Texture. So the sprite's hitbox starts in the center of the texture I set

Comment: Then the problem is where you create the hitbox (`sf::Sprite` does not have a hitbox or anything like that, just shows the texture). Shows the code where you create the hitbox.